# How to Kill Processes on hitting a button flex spark

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

When I send request to backend(java) its taking time to get the response, so If I hit cancel button, it only removing my title window but the process is still going on. So, after hitting cancel button how to stop Listening to the response immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If remoteObject is using then we can cancel listening to the response by this small line

remoteObject.getOperation("serviceYouWantToStop").cancel();

Comment: The "Cancel" method on the RemoteObject class doesn't do this for you directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can stop listening for a response by removing the event listeners for the response.  How you do this depends on the service you're using and how you call it, but generically like this:

```
myService.removeEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, myResultHandler);
myService.removeEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, myFaultHandler);
```

You should consider editing your question to provide those details.  To actually stop the RemoteObject call, you can use the [cancel()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#cancel%28%29) method of HTTPService; the [disconnect()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/AbstractService.html#disconnect%28%29) method on RemoteObject and a [disconnect()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/AbstractService.html#disconnect%28%29) method on WebService

Comment: Actually I'm using java remote objects.

Comment: The the cancel() method it is.